# Reordering Treenodes in C#.NET

Tags: treeview

I have a Visual Studio 2005 C#.NET GUI application. I want to provide the flexibility to reorder the treenodes in the treeview just by dragging and dropping them wherever desired. Is that possible by using any property of the treeview class? Or do I have to do it the hard way by writing events for mouseup and then sensing the dragging of the node etc etc. Any help would be apreciated.

Thanks,
Viren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem that microsoft itself answered at least a part of your question : [kb 307968: How to add TreeView drag-and-drop functionality in a Visual C# application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307968).